# group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateTrade, 111) not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want  average values every 15 minutes ordered by DateTime without time. I have the Group by this Date but it is not working

I used an example I found at stackoverflow

```
declare @interval int = 15
select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateTrade, 111) as dateo,
dateadd(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '01-jan-1970', DateTrade)/@interval*@interval, '01-jan-1970') as d,
        avg(price) as Av,
        avg(Volume) as Mn

FROM     [crypto].[dbo].[TradesOutros]
WHERE   MOEDA = 'XBTEUR' 
group by  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateTrade, 111), 
          DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '01-jan-1970', DateTrade)/@interval

2019/07/21  2019-07-21 01:15:00.000 9618.55882352941    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 06:15:00.000 9495.1975   0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 16:00:00.000 9450.4  0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 00:45:00.000 9584.55702479338    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 01:45:00.000 9357.92093023256    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 12:30:00.000 9358.6125   0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 01:00:00.000 9400.625    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 01:30:00.000 9641.80862068965    0
2019/07/19  2019-07-19 13:45:00.000 9379.46498054474    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 11:45:00.000 9450.77111111111    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 17:30:00.000 9528.33571428571    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 06:30:00.000 9471.74 0
2019/07/19  2019-07-19 23:00:00.000 9430.88153846153    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 02:15:00.000 9653.6696969697 0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 11:00:00.000 9436.05131578947    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 16:45:00.000 9479.03936170213    0
2019/07/19  2019-07-19 13:00:00.000 9328.71529902643    0
2019/07/19  2019-07-19 23:45:00.000 9347.04615384615    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 07:15:00.000 9476.14444444445    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 10:15:00.000 9465.43484848485    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 05:00:00.000 9472.26461538461    0
2019/07/20  2019-07-20 15:15:00.000 9434.18101265823    0
2019/07/18  2019-07-18 23:15:00.000 9377.66666666667    0
2019/07/21  2019-07-21 05:45:00.000 9511.025    0
2019/07/19  2019-07-19 10:45:00.000 9229.85 0
```

Comment: you might replace `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '01-jan-1970', DateTrade)/@interval` with `dateadd(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '01-jan-1970', DateTrade)/@interval*@interval, '01-jan-1970')` within the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: (1) How is this not working?  (2) What is really your question?  You seem to have a viable query.

Comment: Barbaros, if this is the Group By clause you suggested it did not worked but I have already the solution by Gordon.

Comment: group by  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateTrade, 111), dateadd(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '01-jan-1970', DateTrade)/@interval*@interval, '01-jan-1970')

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results ordered, you need an `order by`.  I see no reason to repeat the date twice, so I would remove that from the query:

```
declare @interval int = 15;

select dateadd(minute,
               @interval * (datediff(minute, '1970-01-01', DateTrade) / @interval),
               '1970-01-01'
              ) as d,
       avg(price) as Av,
       avg(Volume) as Mn
from [crypto].[dbo].[TradesOutros]
where MOEDA = 'XBTEUR' 
group by dateadd(minute,
                 @interval * (datediff(minute, '1970-01-01', DateTrade) / @interval),
                 '1970-01-01'
                )
order by min(DateTrade);
```

Note that your original `group by` expression is fine.  However, it is a little confusing when reading the query to understand that all the operations on the that expression involve constants.

Also note the use of standard date formats.  This is always a best practice.  SQL Server has a slight preference for the versions with no hyphens (`'19700101'`), but I prefer the ISO standard format.

Comment: I thought that "group by" implicitly would order by the Date but no. Your query worked perfect.

Comment: I am not a professional so I find examples  for c#, wpf e sql server, mainly, at stackoverflow. Those constants were part of the example I found first. As was not grouping (ordering) by date I added the "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateTrade, 111)" at Group By clause. The variables returned at example were only for testing. In truth I only need "d" and "av".

Comment: @LuisNovaisReis . . . `GROUP BY` does not enforce ordering.  `ORDER BY` does.